# Excel comma separated field based on values from multiple columns

Tags: arrays, excel, csv

I have data in Excel which looks like

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | N | Y | Y |
| N | Y | Y | N |

I want a column at the end which shows a comma separated list of the headings which = 'Y'. So it would look like:

| A | B | C | D | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | N | Y | Y | A, C, D |
| N | Y | Y | N | B, C |

Comment: Please include your attempted formula for debugging purposes. Also, can you let us know what version of Excel you are working with?

Comment: Are A, B, C part of the data or the column headers from Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use these formulas:

If the column headers, you want to join, are in row 1:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE, FILTER(A1:D1,A2:D2="Y",""))`

If you want to use Excels column headers then you first have to map the column to a letter and then do the filtering and joining:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(MAP(A2:D2,LAMBDA(c,CHAR(64+COLUMN(c)))),A2:D2="Y"))`

Comment: Sorry forgot to specific that row 1 contains the headers. Your top example therefore works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Array version: `=BYROW(A2:D3, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",, FILTER(A1:D1,x="Y",""))))`